# How can I check to see if row exists in two databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not quite sure on the correct way to see if a row exists in both databases. Please help.

```
@pStoreNum bigint,
@pGuid varchar(100)

IF EXISTS (SELECT Guid FROM dbo.StoreSales WHERE Guid = @pGuid 
AND SELECT Guid FROM dbo.StoreReporting  WHERE Guid = @pGuid)
BEGIN
UPDATE
    dbo.StoreReporting 
SET 
    ValidCount = ValidCount + 1
WHERE
    StoreNum = @pStoreNum
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify EXISTS twice:

```
IF EXISTS (first select) AND EXISTS (second select)
BEGIN
...
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Guid FROM dbo.StoreSales ss
           INNER JOIN dbo.StoreReporting sr
               ON sr.Guid = ss.Guid
           WHERE ss.Guid = @pGuid)
```

This will check that it's in both tables.  The `INNER JOIN` will limit the result set to rows that have the same `GUID` in both tables, so if it exists in that `JOIN`ed result set it exists both places.